# Adding props to constructor as this.prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a number of methods in a React class component. The component itself receives a number of props.

I am wondering if I should take the props and add each of them as `this.propName` in the constructor and then access the props using `this.propName`. Here is an example. What is best practice?

```
const classComponent = class classComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props) 
    this.propA = props.propA
    this.propB = props.propB
  }

  methodA() {
    console.log(this.propA)
  }
}
```

**Alternative**

```
const classComponent = class classComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props) 
  }

  methodA() {
    console.log(this.props.propA)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a *primarily opinion-based* question because you're going to get a lot of **opinions** based of experiences, Etc.  Therefore, this question should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official documentation of React.js in [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) section says:

> While `this.props` is set up by React itself and `this.state` has a special meaning, **you are free to add additional fields to the class manually if you need to store something that is not used for the visual output**.

In your case, most likely it should stay as a `prop`. Whenever you pass anything as a parameter, which in React.js philosophy would be a `prop`, it's most likely an ingredient of the visual effect.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a variable it uses memory and, even if you are referencing a type, like an array or an object, you make your file bigger. Creating new names for variables already accessible to your class/function make no sense, so don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you handled the `props` does not allow the component to update when it receives new props; mainly because `constructor` is only called once--at the creation of the component.

A better way to do it is to use Destructuring assignment in the `render` function:

```
render() {
  {propA, propB, ...rest} = this.props;
  //Rest code here, using propA, propB
  //However, don't use this.propA, or this.propB
}
```

If you still like to do the way you want to do, you have to add the following function inside your component, to make your component update whenever it receives new props:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.propA = nextProps.propA;
  this.propB = nextProps.propB;
}
```

As you can see, unnecessary code had to be included, so I think this is a wrong way to do it!